# JQGRID - Is it possible to change the background color of HTML header text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

Is it possible to change the background color of HTML header text in JavaScript?

Edited: oops - i did forget to add that is it header text in jqGrid..
i'm sorry about that..

Comment: Yes! (Sorry, I really need to see the markup you want to style, "header text" is *way* too vague.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for you all!!
the answers helps me to find the answer.

```
var HeaderFontColor = "yellow";
var HeaderBackgroundColor = "brown";
$(".ui-jqgrid-sortable").each(function() {
    this.style.color = HeaderFontColor;
    this.style.backgroundColor = HeaderBackgroundColor;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is not needed, you can do this with regular JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("headerID").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

Comment: (any particular reason why the square-bracket property accessor?)

Comment: Oy, I was originally thinking in terms of `background-color` and when I got rid of the dash I didn't remove the braces.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set background color of all headers of the jqGrid you can include

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-jqgrid-sortable {background-color:red}
</style>
```

in your HTML page. If you want make the changes for one column only you can use [setLabel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setLabel','Price', '', {'background':'red'});
```

or

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setLabel','Price', '', 'myColorClass');
```

In the case you cannot use `background-color` because jqGrid use jQuery UI per default and every grid element has `background` defined.`To overwrite this you have to use also`background` CSS.

I recommend you customize and download the theme which you use in http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ to have the results looking better.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. `$("h1").css({backgroundColor:"red"})`

Comment: Have you included the jquery library? Is the h1 a block element?