# struts 2 jquery grid plugin change only one column header style

Tags: struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

Is it possible to change the style of only one column heard in grid ?!

The `sjg:gridColumn` has a `cssClass` property, but setting this css will only be applied to rows under the column, not the column header.

At [JQGRID - Is it possible to change the background color of HTML header text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065197/jqgrid-is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-html-header-text-in-ja) I got the code as:

> in your HTML page. If you want make the changes for one column only
>   you can use setLabel method:
>
> `$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setLabel','Price', '', {'background':'red'});`
>
> or
>
> `$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setLabel','Price', '', 'myColorClass');`

But I could not make it work.

Finally, as the columns headers will have unique Id, I could use below:

```
document.getElementById("gridtable_sampleColumn").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

Well do you think there is a better way. I was looking for some thing like this:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="sampleColumn" 
            cssClass="makeThisSmall" />
```

And in my css

```
.makeThisSmall{
  font-size : smaller;
}
```

Which did not work and only change the rows css not column header.

Also I find that the `gridColumn` has a `formatoptions` could this do what I am looking for ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no declarative way to set style/class of the column header for specific column (I exclude definition of the CSS rule where the id or the column name are set explicitly). So you should use `setLabel` to set it.

If you need to change background color then you should take in consideration that `background-image` have to be set to `none` too. Additionally you should don't forget that *other* CSS rules will be applied too and the rule with *more specific* CSS selector will win. For example the `font-size` in the column header will be applied because of the following rule from `ui.jqgrid.css`:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {
    font-size: 11px
}
```

which have **two classes** in the rule. If you want to change the value for columns having `makeThisSmall` class then you should define CSS rule like

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view .makeThisSmall {
    font-size: 8px
}
```

or

```css
.ui-jqgrid-view .makeThisSmall {
    font-size: 8px
}
```

In any way it should be at least so complex or more complex as the CSS rule which you want to overwrite.

In the same way the `background` will be applied because of CSS rule which contains two classes too

```css
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
    background: ...
}
```

So you need define the corresponding deep (or deeper) CSS role too to be able to ovewrite it via `class` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. The struts-2jquery-plugin generates the necessary jQuery statements, so we do not write any javascript ourselves. The problem is that this tag library does not assign a special class to a special column. If I could force the the plugin to do that, then I will use your recommendation for how define the CSS

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: jqGrid not provide and option to assign CSS class *to the column header*. So I'm sure that struts-2jquery-plugin don't have the corresponding option too. So you *have to* assign the class using small JavaScriupt code. The most easy way is the usage of `setLabel` method like I wrote in my answer. In any way you should define more complex CSS rule on the class. The `.makeThisSmall{font-size : smaller;}` will not work because another rule `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {font-size: 11px}` will overwrite it.